# ipad not picking up css style

Tags: css, ipad

I am fixing up for my existing website to have proper layout in iPad. But the problem is iPad is not picking up for css that I have defined for the website. The existing website can display properly in PC browser.

How to solve this?

Example:

```
body{
    padding:0; margin:0;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    font-size: 10px;
    background:#ffffff;
    }
```

In browser, the site is showing Century Gothic font. But in iPad , it is just showing the default font. It is quite obvious that iPad is not picking up my css.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: its quite obvious that it *is* picking up your CSS. otherwise the rest of the styles wouldn't be getting applied either.

Comment: I would suggest using CSS Web Fonts if you want to use that font on an iPad.

Comment: ok Ryan. I will take note of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS does not provide the Century Gothic font.

You can check which typefaces are provided in iOS [by consulting this list](http://iosfonts.com/).